# each 'tr' have different background color

Tags: css

I have list of `tr` in my `table` HTML below:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>content here</td>
    <td>content here</td>
    <td>content here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content here</td>
    <td>content here</td>
    <td>content here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content here</td>
    <td>content here</td>
    <td>content here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content here</td>
    <td>content here</td>
    <td>content here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is that possible to have different background color each `tr` using css for example using `nth-child`

I try this:

```
    table tr:nth-child(1) {
      background-color:#000
    }
```

but It's not working.

Comment: It is working http://jsfiddle.net/p9e45q80/

Comment: As shown in Suresh's fiddle, it is definitely possible to have a different background color for each `tr` and you are on the right track. Is your question more on how to simplify the code instead of having to write one rule for each child?

Comment: how many different colours are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tr:nth-child(2n+1){
   background-color:#000;
}
```

Comment: Not saying the answer is incorrect, but this would do zebra striping and not *different background color for each tr*.

Comment: If you want a specific color for each tr, then you have to manually specify background for each tr or in query you have to iterate to each tr and set specific color by incrementing the color value each time inside loop. Got it..!!

Comment: You can use "cicada principle" (http://www.sitepoint.com/the-cicada-principle-and-why-it-matters-to-web-designers/) to generate large patterns by setting different colors for `tr:nth-child(Nn+A)` and different semi-transparent (`rgba` or `hsla`) tones for `tr:nth-child(Mn+B) > td`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
table tr:nth-child(1)>td {
  background-color:#000
}
```

Comment: While suggesting code/solution, you should brief about the solution you are suggesting!